# Can corrosion from hydrogen peroxide solution model the corrosion protection activities of Al coating?

Tags: electrochemistry

Immersion in hydrogen peroxide can make steel corrode very fast. However, the coated steel resisted the corrosion attack for a span of time, and as time passes, the coating becomes thinner. Some got removed from the subtrate. Can this mechanism be a model for the corrosion protection of the Al coating for research studies? Does this reflect the behavior of metal coating in immersion with other corrosive media like NaCl?

Comment: Still on the same matter. The question is not clear. If you have understood the answer(s) to your previous question, and it is convincing that the Al coated sample got mass due to Al oxide formation, ie the underlying steel was protected by passivation, now you must clarify what you model? If you simply replace NaCl of the previous exp. with H2O2, obviously you will see the same but in a (much) shorter time. Obviously the microscopical and mechanical properties of the Al oxide layer (which in turn depends on those of the initial Al layer) do not guarantee a long standing protection....

Comment: ... and after some time you should get two samples of the same steel with the same properties immersed in hydrogen peroxide solution. At a given time, their relative weight loss will be different due to the fact that one was protected for a while. From a moment, assuming the same surface to volume ratio, they will loose weight at the same ratio.